# How can I generate date-dependent passwords?

Tags: passwords

I'm looking for a simple way to generate passwords that will only work once for a limited amount of time, e.g. 1 day, 1 week, 1 month. This has to be implemented in an application that has no connectivity so a server isn't possible. The use case is something like:
1. Generate password for a specific date and length of time.
2. Send to user (email, phone, etc).
3. User enters in application.
4. Application is enabled for a specific time.
5. Password cannot be reused, even on another PC.

I'm assuming the only way to do this is to generate passwords that only work between a specific set of dates. Can anyone recommend an algorithm that can do this? It doesn't have to be incredibly secure, and I know you can crack this by resetting the time on the PC!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late but I'll provide my advice anyway in case someone else who needs it found their way here.

To prevent it being used on another PC, you could probably use the MAC address or hardware address. However, this is subject to the network hardware being still available when checking the password. Please make sure you use the hardware address of the machine where the password will be checked.

```
    private string GetBase64Mac()
    {
        System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface[] interfaces = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        if (interfaces.Length == 0)
        {
            System.Net.NetworkInformation.PhysicalAddress add = interfaces[0].GetPhysicalAddress();
            if (add != null)
                return System.Convert.ToBase64String(add.GetAddressBytes());
        }
        return "";
    }
```

To limit it by some expiry date simply use the text string of the expiry date.

```
    private string GetExpiryDate(DateTime expiryDate)
    {
        return expiryDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    }
```

Simply use a hash function to hash the combine expiry date, hardware address and a secret key. Prefix or suffix the hash output with the expiry date.

```
    private void GeneratePassword(string prefix)
    {
        string secretKey = "MySecretKey";
        System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 sha = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();
        byte[] preHash = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(prefix + secretKey + GetBase64Mac());
        byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(preHash);
        string password = prefix + System.Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        return password;
    }
```

In the case above, i prefix the hash with the expiry date. So, when we check the password, we simply extract the expiry date from the password, use the same function to generate the same password. If the generated password match the provided password, then you have green light.

```
    private void TestPassword()
    {
        int duration = 15; // in days
        string prefix = GetExpiryDate(DateTime.Today.AddDays(duration));
        string generated = GeneratePassword(prefix);

        // Positive test
        string testPrefix = generated.Substring(0, 8);
        string testPassword = GeneratePassword(testPrefix);

        if (generated != TestPassword)
            return false;

        // Negative test
        generated[2] = '2';
        generated[12] = 'b';

        testPrefix = generated.Substring(0, 8);
        testPassword = GeneratePassword(testPrefix);
        if (generated != TestPassword)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Sample output password:

> 20110318k3X3GEDvP0LkBN6zCrkijIE+sNc=

If you can't get the hardware address, then simply use the customer's name. It won't prevent the password from being used in multiple machines, but it will ensure that the same person is using it.

Answer (score 1):

Your application should have a attribute like validity for the password something like this

```
username password_hash validity_from  Validity_end
xyz      a73839$56     11-Nov-2010    12-Nov-2010
```

and then in your application you can validate that your password has expired or not

Comment: Maybe I should have said key instead of password. There's no username and I don't want to generate the passwords in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Generate passwords by any method you'd like (a word list, random letters, etc). Put them into some data structure, like an associative array, where you can associate a date with each password. Then you consult this data structure in the program that hands out passwords to give one out with the proper expiration date. The client program has the same list of passwords and dates, so when it gets a password, it just looks up the associated expiration date there.

Comment: But that requires passwords to be generated in advance, along with a list of dates. If I expect the software to be used for up to 5 years that's a lot of passwords.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the problem with making this thing work entirely offline. There's a reason all modern software activation requires communication with the software provider. You're either online or you phone in to activate.